# UNNotificationSound doesn't work

Tags: audio, notifications, ios10

Custom sound for new iOS10 User Notification framework doesn't work.
The same file works with old UILocalNotification, but now always is playing default system sound. When i set nil, I have no sound so just that init with name is problematic

```
let notificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
notificationContent.title = "XYZ"
notificationContent.body = "XYZ"
notificationContent.sound = UNNotificationSound(named: "sound_name.aif")
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue! It's not consistent. Custom sound not always work. Big problem.

Comment: I noticed that when you close simulator and open it again, custom sound works for a while

Comment: Ya, same problem here. I also tried to put sound name with/without extension, neither works :(

Comment: aside from all the iOS 10 related issues...for me the issue was because we had multiple targets, and the audio file I added was only added to 1 target. Basically I had to add it to all of our targets.

Comment: I tried a lot of things: using /Library/Sounds reference folder, aiff, caf, linear pcm, launching from archive rather than xcode, still I can't setup a custom notification sound. This discussion is related: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/49512 (I'm developing for mac) I wonder if anybody succeeded, and how...

Answer (score 6):

i changed this line :

```
notificationContent.sound = UNNotificationSound(named: "sound_name.aiff")
```

to :

```
notificationContent.sound = UNNotificationSound.init(named: "sound_name.aiff")
```

and as you can see i converted my sound to `*.aiff`  and after reading API Reference i moved my sound file to a folder called Sounds.

and i made sure my sound file was under 30 seconds

Comment: This doesn't work for me. First of all `UNNotificationSound.init(named: String)` is no longer available. Second of all I would be highly surprised if adding `.init` would make a difference as it's only syntactic sugar AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`UNNotificationSoundName`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationsoundname) struct:

```
if let soundFilename {
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound(named: UNNotificationSoundName(rawValue: soundFilename))
} else {
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
}
```