# Custom Sound for macosx notification

Tags: objective-c, macos, notifications, macos-big-sur

I'm working on project that needs to create a notification in macosx(11.3, Big Sur) with a custom sound.
I have referenced apple official documents and found an obj-c code that should work which is written below.

```
// Configure the notification's payload.
UNMutableNotificationContent* content = [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc] init];
content.title = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:@"Hello!" arguments:nil];
content.body = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:@"Hello_message_body"
            arguments:nil];
content.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];
 
// Deliver the notification in five seconds.
UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger* trigger = [UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger
            triggerWithTimeInterval:5 repeats:NO];
UNNotificationRequest* request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:@"FiveSecond"
            content:content trigger:trigger];
 
// Schedule the notification.
UNUserNotificationCenter* center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
[center addNotificationRequest:request];
```

The code works fine, however, when I fix the code to play a custom sound (example.wav) file. It does not apply and still plays the defaultSound.

```
...
    UNMutableNotificationContent* content = [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc] init];
    content.title = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:@"Hello!" arguments:nil];
    content.body = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:@"Hello_message_body"
                arguments:nil];
    content.sound = [UNNotificationSound soundNamed:@"example.wav"];
...
```

I have copied the wav file by using Xcode (target > Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resource) which copies the file to the bundles `Contents/Resources` directory. I believe that the code from the official document should work and I would appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UNNotificationSound doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39571756/unnotificationsound-doesnt-work)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationsound/1649031-soundnamed?preferredLanguage=occ

Comment: Why are you using a wav file?

Comment: @ElTomato I have tested with an **.aif** file but has not solve the problem.

Comment: @MarekH I have read the link you posted but the answer does not fully answer my problem. In obj-c API the posted code is the correct way to add a custom sound which is mentioned in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unmutablenotificationcontent?language=objc.

Comment: Have you placed AIF sound into Sounds subdirectory as described in the links?

Comment: @MarekH The project I'm working on in a sandboxed application, so the resource file cannot be copied to ~/Library/Sounds directory.

Comment: Read the documentation again The <app_container>/Library/Sounds directory, where <app_container> is the app’s container directory. Sure you can’t create folder and sound like this in sandboxing? Why I can? Try manually first to create in your ~/Library/Containers/<app_container> Also I recommend to study contents if this folder to see whats sandboxing

Comment: @MarekH Thank you for the new approach. I have tested manually coping the file to the Library/Sounds folder but had to reboot to properly play the custom sound. It seems that the macOS only loads the Library/Sounds file at boot time.